# How to exclude the feature.source in tycho-source feature plugin configuration using regex?

Tags: tycho

While using the tycho-source-feature-plugin in pom.xml, the name of the feature with .source is given under excludes. Is it possible to use the regular expression which excludes all the features with .source instead of giving the feature.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-source-feature-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-source-feature-plugin-Version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>source-feature</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>source-feature</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <feature id="myfeature.source" />
                            </excludes>
                            <labelSuffix></labelSuffix>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <labelSuffix></labelSuffix>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It would help if you could provide some background on this.

Comment: You are aware of the [documentation for the tycho-source-feature-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs-extras/tycho-source-feature-plugin/source-feature-mojo.html), right?

Comment: I am maintaining the above configuration in parent pom.xml, I want to exclude the features which ends with .source, Instead of giving all the feature id which needs to be excluded, I just want to have regular expression which excludes all the feature.source.I Want to avoid using <feature id="myfeature1.source" />              <feature id="myfeature2.source" />,instead I need a common regular expression which should exclude both.

Comment: Yes, but what are these features that end in '.source'? Are they source features? If yes, then why do you then include them in the binary feature?

Comment: Yes they are the source features. We need these source features to run the tests ( junit/window tester)